# django queryset annotate all field in childtable

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

models.py

```
class Userinfo(models.Model):

    useruid = models.BigAutoField(db_column='UserUID', primary_key=True)

    useremail = models.CharField(
    db_column='UserEmail', unique=True, max_length=100)

    userpassword = models.CharField(db_column='UserPassword', max_length=128)

    passwordsalt = models.CharField(db_column='PasswordSalt', max_length=128)

    class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'userinfo'

class Postinfo(models.Model):


    postuid = models.BigAutoField(db_column='PostUID',primary_key=True)

    useruid = models.ForeignKey(
    'Userinfo', db_column='UserUID', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    content = models.TextField(db_column='Content')

    class Meta:
          managed = False
          db_table = 'postinfo'
```

if i get userlist and user's last post

i think use annotate

```
models.Userinfo.objects.all().annotate(lastpost="??").order_by("-useruid")
```

what values in "??"

like this form

```
[{userinfo1,"lastpost":{postinfofields}},{userinfo2,"lastpost":{postinfofields}},{userinfo3,"lastpost":{postinfofields}}]
```

can i this query not use forloop?

Serializer.py

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Postinfo
        fields = ('postuid','content') 

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   

     lastpost = PostSerializer() 

     class Meta:
        model = Userinfo
        fields = ['useruid', 'useremail', 'lastpost']
```

view.py

```
  userinfos = models.Userinfo.objects.all().order_by("-useruid")
  result = UserSerializer(userinfos,many=True)
  print(result.data)
```

raise Exception

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `lastpost` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Userinfo` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Userinfo' object has no attribute 'lastpost'.
```

if i add read_only=True print this

```
[OrderedDict([('useuid', 1), ('useremail', 'test')]), OrderedDict([('useruid', 2), ('useremail', 'test2')])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use model's property for this:

```
class Userinfo(models.Model):

    useruid = models.BigAutoField(db_column='UserUID', primary_key=True)

    useremail = models.CharField(
    db_column='UserEmail', unique=True, max_length=100)

    userpassword = models.CharField(db_column='UserPassword', max_length=128)

    passwordsalt = models.CharField(db_column='PasswordSalt', max_length=128)

    @property
    def lastpost(self):
        return self.postinfo_set.latest('postuid')
```

Now you dont need annotation, just use it for example in template like this:

```
{{ user.lastpost.content }}
```

**UPD**

To serialize property with `ModelSerializer` just add serializer's field `'lastpost'`:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Postinfo
        fields = ('postuid','content') 

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    lastpost = PostSerializer() 

    class Meta:
        model = Userinfo
        fields = ['useruid', 'useremail', 'lastpost']
```

**UPD2**

You can also implement logic directly on the serializer level, without model's property. Just use [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    lastpost = SerializerMethodField() 

    class Meta:
        model = Userinfo
        fields = ['useruid', 'useremail', 'lastpost']

    def get_lastpos(self, obj):
        last = obj.postinfo_set.latest('postuid')
        serializer = PostSerializer(last)
        return serializer.data
```

Comment: i have to return dict , can i make dict?

Comment: @Adam try to use serializers.

Comment: sry i don't understand i 'm noob ...

`class serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:

        model = models.Userinfo

        fields = '__all__'

@property

    def lastpost(self):

        return json.loads(serializers.serialize("json", 
self.postinfo_set.order_by('-postuid')[:1]))[0]`


this is right?

Comment: Yes i used drf

I really appreciate what you did. 

 always have good luck

Comment: @Adam I've added example with DRF serializers.

Comment: um... i tried same Serializer but Serializer return empty lastpost

Comment: `[OrderedDict([('useuid', 1), ('useremail', 'test')]), OrderedDict([('useruid', 2), ('useremail', 'test2')])]`

Comment: @Adam it should work, I've just tested it. Can you show what you've done?

Comment: @Adam I've added anothe method to solve your problem. Check it.